# Javascript disabling contents selection

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

on`mousedown` and `draggin`  the contents of Container will be selected. 
How can I disable this selection behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written Prototype.JS methods for this, you can use them.

```
Element.addMethods({
    /**
     * Makes element unselectable. Disables cursor select
     * @param {Object} target
     */
    setUnselectable: function(target){
        if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") {target.onselectstart = function(){return false;};}
        else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") { target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";}
        else {target.onmousedown = function(){ return false;}; }
        return target;
    },
    /**
     * Reverts unselectable effect, Enables cursor select
     * @param {Object} target
     */
    setSelectable: function(target){
        if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") { target.onselectstart = document.createElement("div").onselectstart; }
        else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") { target.style.MozUserSelect = document.createElement("div").style.MozUserSelect; } 
        else { target.onmousedown = ""; }
        return target;
    }
});
```

To make an element unselectable

```
$('element_id').setUnselectable();
```

To revert it back

```
$('element_id').setSelectable();
```

Answer (score 0):

To cover all bases, set all these properties in your css:

> ```
> user-select: none
> -webkit-user-select: none
> -khtml-user-select: none
> -moz-user-select: none
> ```